# Print number without preceding 0

Tags: output-formatting

I would like to print the number

```
0.21534715
```

as

```
.21

NumberForm[0.21534715, {1, 2}]
```

gives me only

```
0.20
```

Comment: `StringTrim[ToString@.21, StartOfString ~~ ("0" ..)]`?

Comment: Great, but I do not understand `StartOfString ~~ ("0" ..)`. Can you write instead a longer expression? Do you have also  solution without converting to `String`?

Comment: [`StartOfString`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StartOfString.html) "represents the start of a string for purposes of matching in `StringExpression`"; `~~` is [`StringExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringExpression.html), and `..` is [`Repeated`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Repeated.html). These are used in [pattern matching](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/StringPatterns.html) and [regular expressions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/RegularExpressions.html).

Comment: You can select each part and hit F1, I am not sure how to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nForm = NumberForm[#, 
   NumberFormat -> (Row[{If[StringStartsQ["0"]@#, StringDrop[#, 1], #], #3}]&)]&;

lst = {000.0123, 123.^7, 00013.123};
nForm[lst]
```

> {.0123,4.2592814,13.123}